# Printer prints text fine, but colors are misaligned

Tags: printing, printer

Got my hands on a used RICOH MP-C3000 printer. Below is a scan of a print of the Google homepage. 
There are two problems with the print (in addition toe the big scan error in the middle!):

1) On the top of the page there's black "dust" spread around.

2) As you can see, the colors are not aligned on top of each other.

When printing pure text (black) the quality is great, but there's still "dust" on the top of the page.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Well black dust is a hint that the printer needs to be cleaned inside. To understand why its not clean you can read up on how a laserpriter works http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printing. The missalignment will be a technical issue, there is maybe something inside that blocks the laserprinter to rotate on normal speed. Black works fine because its only one color. Other colors are mixed from different colors to get a desired result. If i see the picture i would say there is an issue with blue(cyan) or red(magenta) maybe yellow as well but i cant tell 4 sure

Comment: Please don't close this question—this question is about a computer peripheral.

Comment: Alignment issues are typically off just enough to look blurry.  The Google problem is seriously off, like the color mechanisms are not where they're supposed to be (as in internal damage from the printer being dropped or something).  I suspect it will take some disassembly to see what's going on inside.  I don't think any built-in alignment utility will compensate for that much error.  One thing to check: see if all of the user-replaceable parts can be easily removed and reinserted; that nothing has been forced into place off-track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had way to much experience with Ricoh printers.  Simply put, that printer is in major need of service.  With the colors off by that much, you will need a Ricoh tech to come out and do an alignment.  Not to mention a thorough cleaning.

Comment: Thanks, I was just asking in case there was a simple fix. But I guess it's not. I'll call Ricoh and have them look at it.